# php for loop doesn't work

Tags: php, for-loop

I have this php script:

```
<?php
$tmp = $_POST['N1']; 
$tmp = $_POST['N2'];
$tmp = $_POST['N3']; 
$tmp = $_POST['N4']; 
?>
```

I want to use a for loop instead:

```
<?php

for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) { 
$tmp = $_POST['N$i']; 
}
?>
```

How come this doesn't work?

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: @aynber I don't think that's the right choice. Simply `$_POST["N$i"]` should do it.

Comment: i've rolled back the question to where it was asking about PHP, to match the comments, answers, duplicate flag, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in php strings in `'` are parsed as plain text not a variable

use your syntax like this:

```
<?php

for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) { 
$tmp = $_POST["N$i"]; 
}
?>
```

for a better code structure use `foreach` in this case...